# can't edit the logo width further than 130px in the template css

Tags: css, width

im trying to edit the width of the logo but it wont go past 130px and i've tried moving the mainnav but still didnt find what is causing the logo not to fully display as i set it :(

```
    .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.logo h1,
.logo h1 a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 1;
}
.logo-image {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.logo-image h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
}
.logo-image h1 a {
  background-image: url("../images/logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 150px; ![enter image description here][1]
  height: 60px;
}
.logo-image h1 a span,
.logo-image h1 a small {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: can you include the html? just it's parent(s) and including the img.

Comment: my website is http://citadella.co.uk ...you can inspect the elements there yourself...if you need anything else just tell me.thanks.please notice that im not that of a pro in css...:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="span2 logo">
    <div class="logo-image">
        <h1>
            <a href="" class="Citadella"> <!-- this right here -->
```

Hi, your actual logo is displayed on a-tag element and its current width is 200px. No matter what width you set for .span2 or .logo-image it won't change the actual logo's width. So you have to edit your a-tag's style.